# Predict future value with time period using non linear regression model

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, regression

Here I have dataset import from csv file. I want to predict the next value with the time series. Can we use nonlinear regression model to predict the value for next time period or Is there any regression model can we use to predict the value?

Here I upload the subset of my original dataset.

```
 Time     x     x1   x2     y
0:06:00  63    NaN   NaN   63
0:07:00  63    NaN   20    104
0:08:00  104   11     0     93
0:09:00  93    0      0     ?
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is time series data then you should analyze it accordingly, with a time series model. Alternatively, you could build a regression model with polynomials or splines, depending on your data and how "curvy" it is. Another option would be a GAM model (Generalized Additive Model), which works very well with curves of various shapes.

Comment: @ user2974951 Here I upload the graph for refer. Can I use these models which were u described to predict the model according to the graph?

Comment: Your graph is very curvy, so you could use splines or GAM's but not polynomials, that is if you do not want to do time series analysis.

Comment: @ user2974951  Can I use tensorflow or sklearn  to predict my next value in python?

Comment: If they include these models then sure.

Comment: @ user2974951 Okay I will try this method. Thank you. According to my dataset I want to predict the values after one hour one hour (t, t+1, t+2...) , then  how to write the code for that while doing prediction. I tried it and I stuck with this procedure. Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know how Python does this, but there should be a `predict()` function where you can input the desired time.

Comment: @ user2974951 okay I will check. Thank you once again for giving me valuabale suggestions to solve my matter.